# Facing troubles on bringing the Django admin user tools like welcome, view site, log out on the custom template

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have to override the blocks like branding,site_title, and index title to a custom template. But the user tools are not displaying.

How I get.
[image]

How I want.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can update the Site Header from your main urls.py. Just add in:

```
from django.contrib import admin
....
admin.site.site_header = "the title you want"
```

If you want to customise the admin site alot, you will likely want to subclass/override the default admin site. The documentation has most the info you need.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class

> If you’d like to set up your own admin site with custom behavior, you’re free to subclass AdminSite and override or add anything you like. Then, create an instance of your AdminSite subclass (the same way you’d instantiate any other Python class) and register your models and ModelAdmin subclasses with it instead of with the default site. Finally, update myproject/urls.py to reference your AdminSite subclass.

app/admin.py

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite    
from .models import MyModel

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    site_header = 'Monty Python administration'

admin_site = MyAdminSite(name='myadmin')
admin_site.register(MyModel)
```

project/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path    
from myapp.admin import admin_site

urlpatterns = [
    path('myadmin/', admin_site.urls),
]
```